# How to pass shell variable to an awk search pattern?

Tags: shell, awk, quoting

In my bash script I have a variable that I am trying to pass to a pattern to search for using awk. However what I expected to happen is not working. I have the following text file (text.txt):

```
-----------
Task:           a
 (some info)
  ....
------------
Task:           b 
 (some info)
  ....
------------
Task:           c
 (some info)
  ....
------------
```

My script has the following:

```
letter=a
awk -v var="$letter" '/Task .* \var/' RS='-+' text.txt
```

When I do this however I get nothing but if I do the following:

```
awk '/Task .* a/' RS='-+' text.txt
```

I get what I expect:

```
Task:           a
 (some info)
  ....
```

**NOTE:** I need to pass it as a variable because I have a loop that is constantly changing the variable and that's what I am trying to look for. I'd rather use awk since that what I am most familiar with but I am not opposed to hearing other suggestions such as sed or grep.

Comment: Have you tried searching for a solution as this is asked a lot. Try `-v var="$var"`

Comment: I have and I tried using the -v option and that still was giving me an issue.

Comment: Probably best to post the problem with that then. as thats how you pass awk variables

Comment: Is "some info" a fixed number of lines or can it vary?

Comment: It will vary that why I am using the RS separator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could pass the whole pattern to awk

```
letter=a
awk -v pattern="Task .* $letter" -v RS='-+' '
    $0 ~ pattern
' text.txt
```

or construct the pattern as a string in awk

```
letter=a
awk -v ltr="$letter" -v RS='-+' '
    BEGIN {pattern = "Task .* " ltr}
    $0 ~ pattern
' text.txt
```

Since awk variables are not prefixed with `$`, you can't embed them inside a `/regex constant/` -- it's just text in there.

(It's my preference to put all awk variables at the front with `-v`)

Comment: why not `$1 == "Task:" && $2 == ltr` ?

Comment: That's a good idea. However if the contents of `ltr` contains whitespace (or  generally, a field separator), can't match it with a single field comparison.

Comment: One question though what is the `$0 ~ pattern` do?

Comment: @pdm It means the line contains whatever come after. `$0` is the line. `~` is the contains operator.

Comment: Pedantically, `~` is the regular expression matching operator: `string ~ regex` -- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html#Comparison-Operators

Comment: Ohhhh! That makes sense. Thank you for the clarification. You all have been incredibly helpful.

Comment: @glennjackman Yeah, i knew that wasn't the real name writing that but couldn't remember it and thought it would do for explanation purposes. Obviously the real name and your link is more useful though.

Comment: @glennjackman And if I may add this, this is *not* even an `awk` specialty, as some people may think...unless you insist on using a very ancient `bash`, the `~` operator will also work with the `test` shell command (aka `[[ ]]`). If more people knew about this, a lot of `bash` scripts would look way less messy, since the alternate method (i. e. pattern matching) will often make the expression harder to follow than a regular expression would...

Comment: One correction, `test` and `[` are equivalent, and `[[` has some different behaviour. The bash `=~` works with `[[` but not `[` or `test`.

Comment: @syntaxerror - one needn't *insist on using a very ancient `bash`* to render that statement untrue - there are many shells in which `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` is invalid syntax - and all of these that I'm aware of are far faster in practically every respect than any version of `bash` I've ever used. In any case, `~` is the C-language bitwise NOT *(and so also performs that function in shell `$((` arithmetic expansions `))`)* and I've always found the portable `case` construct to be both more useful and more readable than `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` anyway, *(especially because it's faster, too)*.

Comment: @mikeserv Oh you're right, of course I was actually referring to the *combined* operator `~=` where the tilde is followed by an `=` operator. Good catch of yours (as usual). :)

Comment: Almost: this won't work with backslashes. cuonglm's answer is the correct one here.

Comment: What if I wanted to just print the first record separated? How would I modify this command? I tried doing `... 'NR==1($0  ~ pattern)...` but this didn't work.

Comment: If you just want the first one: `$0 ~ pattern {print; exit}`

Answer (score 4):

Your best choice maybe passing variable through environment:

```
letter=a
p="Task: *$letter" awk -v RS='-+' '$0 ~ ENVIRON["p"]' <file
```

or:

```
p="Task: *a" awk -v RS='-+' '$0 ~ ENVIRON["p"]' <file
```

---

Using `-v var=value`, `awk` will expand escape sequences in value. If you want to pass data as-is to `awk` from shell, `-v var="$shell_var"` is not reliable.

Using `ENVIRON` (or `ARGV`) is a more reliable since when `awk` doesn't expand escape sequences in it.

Comment: @mikeserv: Yep, included the explanation in my answer.

Comment: In POSIX awk, can you provide a regex for the RS variable?

Comment: @glennjackman: No, POSIX made it unspecified. I edited my answer to prevent confusing.